# Joomla content not displaying on other computers

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I've build a Joomla website and it has been online for like 2 years now, always worked fine.

Recently I added a Google maps plugin and changed some header images.

Strange thing is, those changes are only displaying on my own laptop. The problem is not that I'm by accident viewing a local website, I'm 100% visiting the website online. I just opened the website on chrome with www.mywebsite.com and it displays all changes made in the backend. When I log out and back in again to the backend trough /administrator I can see the changes.

Now when I open the website on another computer (tried like three different ones), the changes are not displaying. Even when I log in to the backend through /administrator, still online on the same network, I am not seeing the changes made on my laptop and vice versa.

Frontend sometimes can have problems with caching, but the cache is disabled so this can't be the problem. And even if so, why would the backend display other data on 2 different computers..?

Also I've already tried removing the browser cache on those other computers.

Has anyone experienced this problem? I'm guessing it might be a problem on the side of my hosting company..

Comment: Sounds like there might be a cache active somewhere? https://docs.joomla.org/Help34:Site_Maintenance_Clear_Cache

Comment: There is caching in the backend regardless of whether the front end cache is enabled or not. But try clearing the browser cache on your laptop, that's more likely the issue.

Comment: Already tried clearing the browser cache on all those other computers. Did not work unfortunately

Comment: Are u using Chrome or Firefox, did u use Clear cache " the begining of time" option ?

Comment: Tried different browsers, both Firefox and Chrome. Also 'the beginning of time option' did not solve the problem.

Comment: "changed some header images" this is completely static cache and not depending to joomla , so it must be your server cache problem 
but if you want to disable joomla cache dont forget to disable cache plugin too

Comment: Clear the browser cache on the machine where it works.  Also you could try turning error reporting up to developer and see if you are getting an error from the plugin. That's my guess.  Also double check the view settings and make sure you have them set to public if that's how you are looking.

Comment: @Silverboy.ir 'system cache' was already off*

Comment: @elin view settings are on public and caching doesn't seem to be the problem.. Just seems that every other computer is seeing a version of a few months ago and only my laptop displays the latest updates..

Comment: Check the file ownership for the new files. Also definitely turn system reporting to developer and see what's happening. ALso what happens on your laptop if you disable the plugin?

Comment: just for emphasis , system cache that can be disabled in admin control panel is different that cache plugin in plugin manager, please make sure this plugin is disabled too :D

Comment: Problem solved! It had to do with a rule in the hosts-file on my laptop which directed to an old location/ip-adress of the website which has been moved to another server.

Comment: Add an answer below and accept it or delete this question, please.

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with a rule in the hosts-file on my laptop which directed to an old location/ip-adress of the website which has been moved to another server.